# Changing joomlas default favicon path

Tags: php, location, favicon, joomla3.1

I try to change joomlas default favicon and I would like to place it in the root of my web. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Joomla Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Changing_the_site_favicon), the `html.php` looks into both `template` and `root` folder for favicon. Therefor it should show up if you just put in in `root`.

```
// Try to find a favicon by checking the template and root folder
       $path = $directory . DS;
       $dirs = array( $path, JPATH_BASE . DS );
       foreach ($dirs as $dir ) {

              $icon =   $dir . 'favicon.ico';
              if (file_exists( $icon )) {

                     $path = str_replace( JPATH_BASE . DS, '', $dir );
                     $path = str_replace( '\\', '/', $path );
                     $this->addFavicon( JURI::base(true).'/'.$path . 'favicon.ico' );
                     break;''
```